# Python Pandas transpose Date Range of Values

Tags: python, pandas

I have this Python data frame

```
year_month      Type    ID      Values1  Values2    Values3    ...
2022-01           A      1          1         0        0
2022-02           A      1          3         4        6
2022-03           A      1          5         9        10
2022-01           B      2          5         9        10
2022-02           B      2          4         2        1
....             ...    ...        ...
```

I want to transpose my results like this? How I can do this with python?

```
    ID  Type  Values   2022-01  2022-02  2022-03  ...
    1    A    Values1    1       3         5
    1    A    Values2    0       4         9
    1    A    Values3    0       6         10
    2    B    Values1    5       4         0 
    2    B    Values2    9       2         0
    2    B    Values3    10      1         0
   ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot)

```
new = df.pivot(index=['ID', 'Type'], columns='year_month').stack(level=0).reset_index()

year_month  ID Type  level_2  2022-01  2022-02  2022-03
0            1    A  Values1      1.0      3.0      5.0
1            1    A  Values2      0.0      4.0      9.0
2            1    A  Values3      0.0      6.0     10.0
3            2    B  Values1      5.0      4.0      NaN
4            2    B  Values2      9.0      2.0      NaN
5            2    B  Values3     10.0      1.0      NaN
```

you can remove the index name (`year_month`) if you want by doing

```
new.columns.name = ''
```